# how to access i statement in usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, if-statement

How can I go about accessing the result of an if statement in a user control?

```
UserControl code:

public bool SendBack(bool huh)
{
     if(huh)
       huh = true;
     else huh = false;

     return huh;
}
```

And in a separate project i am trying to access it like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyControl.TextControl t = (MyControl.TextCOntrol)sender;
     if(t.SendBack(true))
     {
        // Do something.
     }
}
```

Comment: And what's happening at the moment?

Comment: At the moment it just says "Unable to cast type RichTextBox to MyControl.TextControl" ... And I'm a little confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I thing the sender will be the **button1**, so it will not be castable to your usercontrol...

You will need a reference form the container (form/panel/...) that contains your usercontrol.

Also, I know this might be for simplicity but you can change

```
public bool SendBack(bool huh) 
{ 
     if(huh) 
       huh = true; 
     else huh = false; 

     return huh; 
}
```

to

```
public bool SendBack(bool huh) 
{
     return huh; 
}
```

You might also want to take a look at [Control.ControlCollection.Find Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx)

> Searches for controls by their Name
>   property and builds an array of all
>   the controls that match.

Comment: Sorry I went to press the up arrow but my mouse jumped, undid the downvote :)       -- I am trying to reference the Form containing my usercontrol now :) thank you

Comment: Thank you very very much astander! Control.ControlCollection.Find worked great, now I can access the correct control :)